# The dimension of a division ring over its center is square.

Tags: division-algebras

Let $D$ be a division ring and let $K$ be the center of $D$.

Assume $\dim_K(D)<\infty$.

Why is $\dim_K(D)$ a square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\overline K$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. Then $D\otimes_K\overline K$ is a finite-dimensional simple algebra over $\overline K$. As $\overline K$ is algebraically closed, $D\otimes_K\overline K\cong M_n(\overline K)$. Thus $\dim_K(D)=\dim_K(D\otimes_K\overline K)=n^2$.

Comment: For the fact $D\otimes_K\overline K\cong M_n(\overline K)$, is it by using Artin Wedderburn?

Comment: @Confusedonmath Yes.

Comment: Thank you! I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of Artin Wedderburn by extending the scalar over the algebraic closure, it is simple ring  so it is isonorphic to a matrix ring.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem

Comment: A matrix ring generally has zero-divisors.